# ui-router onEnter() not being called from $state.go() within Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

When using ui-router's `$state.go()` in my **Ionic** app, the `onEnter` method is not called.

The states would be transitioning from `tab.settings` to `tab.queries`. The state transitions fine. How do I get the `onEnter` method to be called from `$state.go()` call? Does `onEnter` not get called when entering child views?

**Route**

```
$stateProvider
.state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})
.state('tab.queries', {
    url: '/queries',
    views: {
        'tab-queries': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-queries.html',
            controller: 'QueryCtrl',
            onEnter: function() {
                activate();
            }
        }
    }
})
.state('tab.settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    views: {
        'tab-settings': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

**SettingsCtrl**

```
vm.removeAll = function() {
    Data.removeAll().then(function() {
        $state.go('tab.queries');
    });
};
```

**QueryCtrl**

```
function activate() {
  console.log('Activating');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the onEnter from within the view object up a level to the state object, I've just ran across this same problem and it seemed to work OK for me.

```
    .state('tab.queries', {
        url: '/queries',
        views: {
            'tab-queries': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-queries.html',
                controller: 'QueryCtrl'
            }
        },
        onEnter: function() {
            activate();
        }
    })
```